# Can you use SQL Views in Geoserver to insert a new database record into a PostGis Datastore?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver, sql-view

I have tried to make an entry into a PostGIS Store in Geoserver using a SQL View in Geoserver with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO marker_shp(gid, id, geom)
VALUES ((SELECT max(gid) FROM marker_shp)+1, (SELECT max(id) FROM marker_shp)+1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (499724.5561430572 5268410.813606716)', 32633))
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: Syntax error at »INTO« Position: 23
```

However, the same Query works fine if I use the same SQL Statement in pgAdmin.

If someone could help me out here I would be very thankful.

All the best:
Thomas :)

Comment: You get an error because of wrong syntax. You may want to check this article also https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-postgresql/9781449309770/ch04s03.html

Comment: You should probably be adding records some other way, possibly using WFS-T

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be

```
 INSERT INTO marker_shp(gid, id, geom) 
 SELECT max(gid) ,  max(id)+1 F,  ST_GeomFromText('POINT (499724.5561430572 5268410.813606716)', 32633))
 FROM marker_shp
```